# Internet Explorer modernizer

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I was wondering if any of you know some libraries that will help/improve the response of IE >= 7 for a website that I have to modify.

I already loaded the modernizr library, but I know that there are some libraries ment to help IE behave as a modern browser should. So, what do you recommend? What options do I have?

I'm really sick of spending hours trying to fix a 1 thing for X Version of IE.

Comment: Do you have to support IE7?  You could urge users with IE7 or less to upgrade or face having a poor experience otherwise.

Comment: Yes, I do have to support IE7, but I also show a message that they should upgrade their browser

Comment: Can you be more specific as to what you are trying to improve?

Comment: @jrummell I'm not trying to improve nothing, just to try and make older browsers act "normal" by applying a javascript library or whatever.

Comment: I wish it were that simple, see my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think it's that simple. I don't know of a single library that makes them all act "normal". A few I use are:

- Modernizr can help with new html5 elements in older browsers
- jQuery for cross browser DOM manipulation
- jQuery UI for cross browser theming

But there is no silver bullet library that works everywhere all the time. Sometimes you will have to adjust the UI based on the browser capabilities. One common method of doing so is called [progressive enhancement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_Enhancement).

> Progressive enhancement is a strategy for web design that emphasizes
>   accessibility, semantic HTML markup, and external stylesheet and
>   scripting technologies. Progressive enhancement uses web technologies
>   in a layered fashion that allows everyone to access the basic content
>   and functionality of a web page, using any browser or Internet
>   connection, while also providing an enhanced version of the page to
>   those with more advanced browser software or better bandwidth.

Comment: Great answer. If you need a special feature, check https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-browser-Polyfills

Answer (score 2):

Check out ie7.js http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/ its not perfect, but it can help with some issues.

Comment: This libraries ability's are far overstated. It handles the transparent image issues well, but few others.

Answer (score 1):

You can tell users they need to install Google Chrome Frame https://developers.google.com/chrome/chrome-frame/

"Google Chrome Frame is an open source plug-in that seamlessly brings Google Chrome's open web technologies and speedy JavaScript engine to Internet Explorer"

Answer (score 1):

I use [CSS3Pie](http://css3pie.com/). This is a .htc file you place on the server which provides poly-fills for many CSS3 styling elements such as border-radius, text shadows, box shadows and gradients. It's quite handy in that is solves many of the same problems for IE8 and IE9 as well.

It can a be a little tricky to set up in that you sometimes need to define a MIME type on your server for .htc and you have to ensure that you set the path in your CSS file to where the .htc file resides, other than that, it's great.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a general fix-all solution for your problem.
I recommend trying this tool called dynaTrace AJAX Edition (http://www.compuware.com/application-performance-management/ajax-performance-testing.html), the free version is more than enough to help you.

What you do is:

1. Start a session and choose your IE browser
2. Open and click through your web application
3. Close the browser
4. Double-click the "Timeline" on dynaTrace.

You'll see a breakdown of your site's performance so you can identify which Javascript is the problem.
You'll also see if the slowdown is simply because your loading external resources which are unavailable - something which I've found IE to handle poorly.